# different no of errors in old Google Search Console and new Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, google-crawlers

Google webmasters tool Search Console giving me different no of crawl errors in older version of Search Console and in new Search Console for the same site.
So which one is correct and which one is wrong ?
Which version of Search Console I should trust and proceed further to fix the errors?

> [OLD VERSION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B688F.png)

and

> [NEW VERSION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnBlB.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of them is correct. This data is acquired, merged and sampled from different data centers, with different time gaps. Beside of this there are differences in whether some errors are reported once, twice (after new crawl).

Don't relate on these numbers - they are only helpful to get patterns, where your site fires errors. If you try to check error urls one by one you loose time and get non meaningful results.

And never ever mark 404 page as repaired, if they remain 404 - in this case Google will crawl this page again and again and report error repeatedly.